# Cast to interface not excluding form members

Tags: c#, json, interface, casting

I am developing an application in C# that has an interface declared on a form:

```
public partial class frmProjectForm : Form, IProjectInfo
{

}

public interface IProjectInfo
{
    string ProjectName { get; set; }
    string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    string ProjectAuthor { get; set; }
    string ProjectCopyright { get; set; }
    string ProjectTrademark { get; set; }
    string ProjectCreationDate { get; set; }
    string ProjectVersion { get; set; }
    string ProjectFileName { get; }
    string ProjectFilePath { get; }
    string FullProjectPath { get; }
}
```

Somewhere in the application I want to do this:

```
frmProjectForm f = new frmProjectForm();
f.ShowDialog(this);
...
...
IProjectInfo getProjectInfoMembersOnly = (IProjectInfo)f;

// persist the IProjectInfo members to JSON
string project = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( getProjectInfoMembersOnly );
```

The `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method is blowing up and complaining of some self-referencing loop on a Button control.  The casting operation is not excluding the form and I don't know why as I just want the interface cast to return only the interface members.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think just casting an instance to an interface will not hide the instance properties when serializing...you are still serializing that instance

Comment: Why are you inheriting a form if you just need the interface properties?

Comment: @AMember I am not actually inheriting a form -- it's a form that inherits an interface.  I wanted to create a standardized form where I can use the `IProjectInfo` interface as a method parameter instead of specifying a concrete form instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems normal to me that a serialization code would work on the object's actual type, not the type passed as parameter (it's even likely that the function accepts a parameter of type `object`, rather than being a generic function `SerializeObject<T>(T obj)`).

If you want your object to be *sliced*, I'm afraid you'll have to perform the slicing yourself, by creating an object implementing the interface and only copying its members.

```
public class ProjectInfo : IProjectInfo
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProjectAuthor { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCopyright { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTrademark { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCreationDate { get; set; }
    public string ProjectVersion { get; set; }
    public string ProjectFileName { get; private set; }
    public string ProjectFilePath { get; private set; }
    public string FullProjectPath { get; private set; }

    public ProjectInfo(IProjectInfo src)
    {
        this.ProjectName = src.ProjectName;
        this.ProjectTitle = src.ProjectTitle;
        this.ProjectDescription = src.ProjectDescription;
        this.ProjectAuthor = src.ProjectAuthor;
        this.ProjectCopyright = src.ProjectCopyright;
        this.ProjectTrademark = src.ProjectTrademark;
        this.ProjectCreationDate = src.ProjectCreationDate;
        this.ProjectVersion = src.ProjectVersion;
        this.ProjectFileName = src.ProjectFileName;
        this.ProjectFilePath = src.ProjectFilePath;
        this.FullProjectPath = src.FullProjectPath;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it this way:

```
frmProjectForm f = new frmProjectForm();
f.ShowDialog(this);
...
...
IProjectInfo getProjectInfoMembersOnly = new ProjectInfo(f); //I only changed this line

// persist the IProjectInfo members to JSON
string project = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( getProjectInfoMembersOnly );
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution.  I already have a concrete class that inherits `IProjectInfo` so I will use this with your slicing suggestion.

Comment: But after seeing @tandrewnichols 's answer, I think it's much better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ONLY using the interface for serialization (unclear from your question), you don't need an interface at all. JSON.NET provides attributes to mark which fields should be serialized. Even if you're using the interface for something else, there's no reason you couldn't define your class like this:

```
// Use optin so you don't have to worry about fields generated by the designer.
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public partial class frmProjectForm : Form
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectAuthor { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectCopyright { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectTrademark { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectCreationDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectVersion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectFileName { get; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ProjectFilePath { get; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string FullProjectPath { get; }

    // . . . Other properties, buttons, and form fields
}
```

Then, when you call `JSONConvert.SerializeObject()`, only fields marked as `JsonProperty` will be serialized.